# How can I get stone if there is only sand everywhere?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm trying to setup a forge to get some iron, but I'm faced with having no stone; there's only sand, everywhere. I tried digging much deeper in a slew of different places, but I still just hit sand or some other weak material.

How do I get stone?

Answer (score 14):

Dig even deeper. There is ALWAYS stone down there. The whole world is made of the stuff! Some areas have as much as 10 or 12 layers of sand and soil on top of the stone, and you just have to keep going down.

Comment: Delve deep, delve greedily!

Comment: Nothing bad has ever happened when dwarves dug too deep!

Comment: @Exal And if you find deposits of a strange, light-blue mineral, that's your reward for your determination! Just dig it right up and smelt it!

Answer (score 1):

Trading with merchants on your Trading Depot.